# Highcharts Heatmap colorAxis stops no gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, colors, heatmap

I have successfully created a heatmap using highcharts module heatmaps

The examples show how you can set the colors, and define a number of color stops, with a nice color gradient in between stops. When I try to define my color stops, I do not get the smooth gradient between stops, each value seems to approximate to its nearest stop...

I have a fiddle to show this http://jsfiddle.net/qpe3bqbx/2/

I wonder if this is because I am using 9 stops, rather than the 3 in the examples. Is there a max number of stops?

```
stops: [
            [0, '#00007F'],
            [0.125, 'blue'],
            [0.25, '#007FFF'],
            [0.375, 'cyan'],
            [0.5, '#7FFF7F'],
            [0.625, 'yellow'],
            [0.75, '#FF7F00'],
            [0.875, 'red'],
            [1, '#7F0000']
        ]
```

Here is the original example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you cannot mix hex colors with color name... it cannot define the gradient between #00007F and blue, so you have to use:

```
stops: [
            [0, '#00007F'],
            [0.125, '#0000ff'],
            [0.25, '#007FFF'],
            [0.375, '#00ffff'],
            [0.5, '#7FFF7F'],
            [0.625, '#ffff00'],
            [0.75, '#FF7F00'],
            [0.875, '#ff0000'],
            [1, '#7F0000']
```